# EmberJS Component - Run custom function after DOM has fully loaded

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I'm struggling to fully grasp the component lifecycle.  I've created a component, but I need my custom javascript function to run after the DOM is complete.  I've scoured through the EmberJS Docs and Stackoverflow, but any documentation I come across doesn't work as I intended.

**My Issue**

I've attempted to use `didInsertElement` and `didRender`, but they still get called before my repeating elements have loaded in the DOM.  How do I circumvent this to have my Javascript run after the DOM has fully rendered.

**My Attempts**

*Below is an extremely stripped down and barebones example using an `alert` in place of my script.  The desired outcome is to have this `alert` appear after the DOM is rendered, the below examples have it alert before.*

```
import Component from '@ember/component';

export default Component.extend({

     didRender() {
        alert('didRender');
     },

     didInsertElement() {
        alert('didInsertElement');
     }
});
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what do you mean by "rpeating elements"?

Comment: The component is adding an image gallery using a json feed.  This list of elements is being generated in a repeater.  {{#each foo as |bar|}}<li></li>{{/each}}

Comment: so you want to run code _exactly_ when all of those finish?
I think you could do it by wrapping your each block in a component, and using the didRender / didInsertElement in there

Comment: The each block is already in a components .hbs, that's why the confusion has ensued.  From everything i read it should render my function "after" the DOM has been created, it is not doing that.  In theory, i'd expect either of these to work as componentDidMount() {} does in React.

Comment: it does work like componentDidMount in React.
I'll explain in an answer, one sec

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have the following template

```
{{#each this.items as |item|}}
  <ItemComponent @item={{item}} />
{{/each}}
```

You want to know when the the list is done rendering?

extract the above template into a component.

```
<ItemList @items={{this.items}} />
```

where `ItemList` is defined as

```
import Component from '@ember/component';
export default class ItemList extends {
  didInsertElement() {
    console.log('list was inserted'); 
  }
}
```

Here is the code:

https://canary.ember-twiddle.com/6e023f1413fbce6bab8954f3eec73554?openFiles=templates.components.item-list.hbs%2Ctemplates.components.item-component.hbs

If you open the console, you'll see:

```
item 1 was inserted
item 2 was inserted
item 3 was inserted
item 4 was inserted
item 5 was inserted
list was inserted
```

Answer (score 0):

Although creating a child component is always safe, ( as said in ember's [docs](https://www.emberjs.com/api/ember/release/classes/Component/events/didInsertElement?anchor=didInsertElement)

`When a view has children, didInsertElement will be called on the child view(s) first and on itself afterwards.`
)

, however, even without child components, the didInsertElement hook will trigger only after the component is inserted to DOM. Here is an example [twiddle](https://canary.ember-twiddle.com/f12a75c8041706f10c22ea7bdf3dbba0?openFiles=templates.components.item-list.hbs%2C).